# Pillow: converting a TIFF from greyscale 16 bit to 8 bit results in fully white image

Tags: image, python-imaging-library, tiff

I know that there are multiple similar questions on SO, but I have tried multiple proposed solutions to no avail.

I have the following TIFF image that opens in Pillow as `type='I;16'`.

[Google Drive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s6fxkwhqEl_jO9V242CfChI9-8m47QB9/view?usp=sharing)

Based on this SO question, I wrote this code to convert it:

```py
def tiff_force_8bit(image, **kwargs):
    if image.format == 'TIFF' and image.mode == 'I;16':
        array = np.array(image)
        normalized = (array.astype(np.uint16) - array.min()) * 255.0 / (array.max() - array.min())
        image = Image.fromarray(normalized.astype(np.uint8))

    return image
```

However, the result is a completely white image.

I have tried other solutions too, such as this:

```py
table = [i/256 for i in range(65536)]
image = image.point(table, 'L')
```

with the same result: full white out.

Can anyone shed some light?
Thanks!

Comment: Hi @MarkSetchell, I didn't have time to investigate what else in my image pipeline might be causing that, but given that you tried the code, I assume you are right in your assumption that something else is causing my issue, so I accepted your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code. If you run:

```
# Open image
im = Image.open('NGC 281 11-01-2021 Ha 1.15.tif')

# Force to 8-bit
res = tiff_force_8bit(im)

# Check min and max of result
res.getextrema()                           # prints (0,255) as expected

# Save as PNG
res.save('result.png')

# Display it
res.show()
```

I can only guess there is a problem with your installation or the way you display the result.

[image]